# Gekko unreachable server, local solving json file error

Tags: python, server, gekko

I think I'm running into the same problem as this stack overflow.

[Unreachable server working with GEKKO. What is going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624215/unreachable-server-working-with-gekko-what-is-going-on)

Yesterday I was able to solve my Gekko model and today I'm not even able to solve the examples from the Apmonitor site. Solving takes forever and I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No solution or server unreachable.
  Show errors with m.solve(disp=True).
  Try local solve with m=GEKKO(remote=False).
```

I tried solving it locally as was suggested in the stack overflow post I mentioned above:

```
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
```

However, I then got the following error:

```
Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

and

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/mr/kgzm2xln40dcc10zkq06drhc0000gn/T/tmpzqxlyw7_gk_model0/options.json'
```

Is the server down and can anyone help me solving it locally?

Edit, code add:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)           # create GEKKO model
y = m.Var(value=2)    # define new variable, initial value=2
m.Equation(y**2==1)   # define new equation
m.options.SOLVER=1    # change solver (1=APOPT,3=IPOPT)
m.solve(disp=True)
print('y: ' + str(y.value)) # print variable value
```

Comment: Could you post your code so that we can help with the local solution? The local solve is sometimes different than the remote server solve because of licensing restrictions on the linear solvers in IPOPT. You can also try `m.options.SOLVER=1` for APOPT or `m.options.SOLVER=2` for BPOPT as different solvers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added the code in the original question. I tried a very basic problem to make sure that is not where the problem is/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Local Solve Error with `remote=False`**
The error that you referenced is because either the solver failed to find a solution or because you are on a MacOS and need some shared libraries with `gcc`. If you are on a MacOS, try installing `gcc` to get the required shared libraries as mentioned in the [GitHub issue discussion for local solution on MacOS.](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/79)

```
brew install gcc
```

If it is a solver issue, you can see the error message if you display the solver output with:

```py
m.solve(disp=True)
```

The local solve is sometimes different than the remote server solve because of licensing restrictions on the linear solvers in IPOPT or because your local executable doesn't have one of the solvers (e.g. IPOPT isn't available for [local solve on MacOS, ARM Linux, or x86-64 Linux](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServer) yet). The `apm` executable that handles local requests automatically reverts over to the next available solver option if the requested one isn't available. You can try `m.options.SOLVER=1` for APOPT or `m.options.SOLVER=2` for BPOPT as different solvers.

Also, you should leave the debug level at `1` if you want to throw an exception when the solver is not successful at finding the solution. Otherwise, set `debug=0` and use `m.options.APPSTATUS` to determine if the solver was successful.

```py
m.solve(disp=True,debug=0)
if m.options.APPSTATUS==0:
    print('Solver failed to find a solution')
else:
    print('Successful solution')
```

We can offer more specific suggestions on getting your program working locally if you can post a [minimal example that shows the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

**Cloud Computing with `remote=True`**

The public server was unavailable for a few hours today but is back up now. Because of the popularity of Gekko, the servers can sometimes get overloaded or are unavailable with occasional maintenance activities. A dedicated APMonitor server is available as a [compute server for Linux](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServerLinux) or as a [compute server for Windows](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServer) if you'd like to host your own system in the cloud or as a dedicated server. If you do create your own server then use:

```py
m = GEKKO(server='http://10.0.0.10',remote=True)
```

but substitute `10.0.0.10` for the IP address of the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a minimal example to the original question. Is there anyway to get an IPOPT solver for mac? Might installing gcc using **brew install gcc** work? I read this in another post of yours.

Comment: I indeed needed **brew install gcc**. Local solving works right now.